# Angular 2+ multiple buttons and passing an object to child component within ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

New to Angular I am having a few issues, I have two components, the parent is search results the child is a summary/detail view of a particular result.  I am having issues getting data from the results to pass to the summary. The Company name is shown in the results component but none of the details are shown in the summary component. I am using an Input to try to pass the Company data into the child component. I've seen people do something similar to this but with the ngFor directly on the child component.

The other issue I'm having is that only the last button works to go back to the results view.  Is there a better way to switch between showing the results or the summary than the events and ngIfs that I have?

Here is my code.

results.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanySummary } from '../company-summary/CompanySummary';

@Component({
    selector: 'search-results',
    templateUrl: './results.component.html'
})

export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        this.showResults = true;
        this.companySummarys = [];
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showResults = true;
    //mock data
    this.companySummarys = [
        new CompanySummary(
            false,
          "12345",
          "Test Company 1",
          "123 Angular Avenue West",
          "Apt. 31415926",
          "Javascriptville",
          "CA",
            94115),
        new CompanySummary(
            false,
            "22222",
            "Test Company 3",
            "123 Angular Avenue West",
            "Apt. 31415926",
            "Javascriptville",
            "CA",
            94115),
        new CompanySummary(
            false,
            "33333",
            "Test Company 4",
            "123 Angular Avenue West",
            "Apt. 31415926",
            "Javascriptville",
            "CA",
            94115),
        new CompanySummary(
            false,
            "54321",
            "Test Company 2",
            "123 JQuery Blvd",
            "",
            "Javascriptville",
            "CA",
            94115)
    ]
}

companySummarys: Array<CompanySummary>;
showResults: boolean;

showCompanySummary(companySummary: CompanySummary): void {
    console.log('Entering showCompanySummary');
    this.showResults = false;
    companySummary.showSummary = true;
}

handleHideEvent(event): void {
    console.log('Entering handleHideEvent');
    this.showResults = true;
    } 
}
```

results.component.html

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let companyResult of companySummarys">
    <div *ngIf="showResults" (click)="showCompanySummary(companyResult)">
      {{companyResult.name}} : Click for details
    </div>
    <company-summary *ngIf="companyResult.showSummary" 
(hide)="handleHideEvent($event)" [companySummary]="companyResult"></company-summary>
  </md-list-item>  
</md-list>
```

company-summary.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanySummary } from './CompanySummary';

@Component({
    selector: 'company-summary',
    templateUrl: './company-summary.component.html'
})
export class CompanySummaryComponent{
    @Input() companySummary: CompanySummary;

    @Output() hide: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    //Event emitter to hide the Company Summary and let the Search Results know to show themselves.
    hideSummary(): void {
        console.log('emmiting hide summary event');
        this.companySummary.showSummary = false;        
        this.hide.emit(null);
    }
}
```

company-summary.component.html

```
<div class="search-summary">
  <h2>Summary</h2>
  <div><p>{{companySummary.Name}}</p></div>
  <div><p>{{companySummary.CompanyAddress1}}</p></div>
  <div><p>{{companySummary.CompanyAddress2}}</p></div>
  <div><p>{{companySummary.City}}</p></div>
  <div><p>{{companySummary.State}}</p></div>
  <div><p>{{companySummary.ZipCode}}</p></div>
  <button md-raised-button type="button" (click)="hideSummary()">Back</button>
</div>
```

CompanySummary.ts

```
export class CompanySummary {
    constructor(
        public showSummary: boolean,
        public id: string,
        public name: string,
        public streetAddress1: string,
        public streetAddress2: string,
        public city: string,
        public state: string,
        public zipCode: number) { }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your `company-sumary.component.html` is looking for the wrong properties. Your CompanySummary object has property name, but in your html it is looking for Name. Similar for the rest including CompanySummary property of streetAddress1/2, but html is looking for CompanyAddress1/2

Comment: Jeez, my attention to detail is horrible. Thanks for point that out it's working now.